# 'Model' conflicts with the declaration Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

EDIT:

```
<p>
  <span class="strong">Fax Number:</span>&nbsp 
  @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.FaxNumber)
</p>
<p>
  <span class="strong">Contact Name:</span>&nbsp 
  @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.ContactFirstName) &nbsp
  @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.ContactLastName)
</p>
<p>
  <span class="strong">Contact Audit Date:</span>&nbsp
  @if (item.AuditDate.HasValue != null)
  {
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.AuditDate.Value.ToString("d"))
  }
```

I spent good amount of time trying to figuring out why I'm getting this error and I have scan the net but did not get any solution, I'm trying to check to see if the value is null but I'm getting the following error:

in my view :

```
@model myapp.Models.Employee

@if(Model.AuditDate.HasValue !=null) <<<< getting error on Model here
{  
     @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.AuditDate.Value.ToString("d"))
};
```

> 'Model' conflicts with the declaration
>   'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model'

Comment: Not related, but its just `@if(Model.AuditDate.HasValue) {`

Comment: Are you sure you don't have something like `@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.SomeProperty)` somewhere else in your view (capital M)?

Comment: `Model` is a reserved keyword in the view (you can't use it in a lambda expression), so use `@Html.DisplayFor(m =>  m.FaxNumber)` etc.

Comment: I tried to use `m` or `model` or what not and still getting this error so if I used `m` then the error is: `The name 'm' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: the error is only happening to the `@if(m.AuditDate.HasValue`

Comment: I mean just for the strongly types helpers - `@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.FaxNumber)` will definitely throw that error so change it to `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FaxNumber)` (and the other 3 instances you have shown). Your still use `@if(Model.AuditDate.HasValue)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I'm not sure if you understand the problem if I use `@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.FaxNumber) ` I'm not getting any error and I have used all over the view... its very strange that I'm getting error only when if I use here >>> `@if(Model.AuditDate.HasValue)`

Comment: I assure you if you do as I say, the error will go away (I have already tested it in my project). If you have both `@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.SomeProperty)` and then also use `Model` to reference a property (as in `@if(Model.AuditDate.HasValue)`) then you get that error. In fact if you reverse it and put `@if(Model.AuditDate.HasValue)` before the `DisplayFor()` methods then you will get a different error - `A local variable name 'Model' cannot ....`

Comment: Will you post as a answer with steps what should I do?

Comment: I have replace entire my view from `Model` to `m` please see the updated question still getting error only on `@if(m ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `Model` keword in the following statement

```
@if (Model.AuditDate.HasValue != null)
```

and you are also using the `Model` keyword in your lambda expressions for the `@Html.DisplayFor()` helpers causing the error. Note if you put the `if` statement before all your `DisplayFor` helpers you would get a different error

> A local variable named 'Model' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'Model` ...

Change you code to

```
<p>
  <span class="strong">Fax Number:</span>&nbsp 
  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FaxNumber)
</p>
<p>
<span class="strong">Contact Name:</span>&nbsp 
  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ContactFirstName)&nbsp
  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ContactLastName)
</p>
<p>
  <span class="strong">Contact Audit Date:</span>&nbsp
  @if (Model.AuditDate.HasValue)
  {
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.AuditDate.Value.ToString("d"))
  }
</p>
```

Note the use of `m` in the helper rather that `Model`, although it could be `x` or `model` (lowercase) or anything except `Model`)

Note also its just `@if (Model.AuditDate.HasValue)`, not `@if (Model.AuditDate.HasValue != null)`.

However it would be better to define the format using a `DisplayAttribute`

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMMM yyyy"})]
public DateTime? AuditDate { get; set; }
```

and just use `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.AuditDate)`. The `if` block is not required. If `AuditDate` has a value, it will be rendered according to the format, otherwise if its `null`, nothing will be rendered.

Comment: sigh!... I got it now so I should have use in the entire view instead of `Model` use `m or model or what not` and when it comes to doing any checks just use directly `Model`, thanks for your help -:)